# "react-native run-ios" does not work in React-Native CLI

Tags: ios, react-native

I got an error when I try to run an ios simulator by typing the command "react-native run-ios"

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/hwang.the.human/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bume-acqblaklgwcoekcyoadgwcbjjufb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/hwang.the.human/Desktop/GitHub/Apps/Bume/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /Users/hwang.the.human/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bume-acqblaklgwcoekcyoadgwcbjjufb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperConnectionManagerImpl.o /Users/hwang.the.human/Desktop/GitHub/Apps/Bume/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperConnectionManagerImpl.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

Comment: Have you tried to run npx pod-install in terminal?

Comment: Yes and it did not help